# The "deliver_sm_resp" command in jSMPP

Tags: smpp, jsmpp

I want to use [jSMPP](https://jsmpp.org/) for implementing a Receiver Listener for [SMSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_service_center). So I want to implement the `MessageRecieverListener` and the method `onAcceptDeliverSm`, but according to the SMPP [specs](http://opensmpp.org/specifications.html) the application should send `deliver_sm_resp` as a response to `deliver_sm` command.

How will this be accomplished through jSMPP, is this something that is performed behind the scenes by the jSMPP library?

Comment: After some investigations I found out that JSMPP is doing this behind the scenes already

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using jSMPP in the production. The best thing of this lib is that many low level things happen behind the scenes and `deliver_sm_resp` too :-)

The `enquery_link` and `enquery_link_resp` commands happen behind the scenes too and you can also configure the timeout for this commands when you create your `SMPPSession` like this:

```
SMPPSession tmpSession = new SMPPSession();
tmpSession.setTransactionTimer(transactionTimer);
tmpSession.setEnquireLinkTimer(enquireLinkTimer);
tmpSession.addSessionStateListener(new SessionStateListenerImpl());

MessageReceiverListenerImpl mrl = new MessageReceiverListenerImpl();
tmpSession.setMessageReceiverListener(mrl);

tmpSession.connectAndBind(remoteIpAddress, remotePort, bindParam);
```

The values of `transactionTimer` and `enquireLinkTimer` I store in the properties file.

jSMPP is very cool lib and I like it :-)

Comment: Yes true, this was long time , we already delivered the project and yes it happened behind the scenes, accept the answer for future reader  :)